# validation for user's input Java

Tags: java, validation

New to Java, please help.
Need validation to not accept negative numbers.
Created 2D array to display Divisions and Quarters, user prompted to enter data - has to be not negative, then data will be displayed per Division/Quarter, if negative, user to be prompted to reenter.
Validation is not working, where should I please validation, shall I call it in Main method as well? 
My code so far...

```
//2D array to hold numbers of divisions and quarters
double [][] companyInfo; 


/**Method displays company info
@param company info.
*/

public static void enterSalesFigures(double [][] companyInfo)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //Create a scanner object

    /*Validation for user's input
    while (companyInfo [divisionIndex][divisionIndex] < 0) 
    {
     System.out.println("Please enter the number that is more than or equal to one.");
     companyInfo [divisionIndex][divisionIndex] = scanner.nextDouble();
    }*/ 

        for(int divisionIndex = 0; divisionIndex < companyInfo.length; divisionIndex++)
        {
        for(int quarterIndex = 0; quarterIndex < companyInfo[0].length; quarterIndex++)
        {
            System.out.printf("Division %d, Quarter %d   ", divisionIndex + 1, quarterIndex + 1);
                    companyInfo [divisionIndex][divisionIndex] = scanner.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}


public static void listSalesFigures(double [][] companyInfo)
{
    double difference;//to hold difference value

    for(int divisionIndex = 0; divisionIndex < companyInfo.length; divisionIndex++)
    {
        difference = 0;

        System.out.printf("|Division %d|\n", divisionIndex +1);

        for(int quarterIndex = 0; quarterIndex < companyInfo[0].length; quarterIndex++)
            {
                if(quarterIndex >= 1)
                {
                    difference = companyInfo[divisionIndex][quarterIndex] - companyInfo[divisionIndex][quarterIndex - 1];
                }
            System.out.printf("|Quarter %d|: $%,.2f,\t\t |Difference To Previous Quarter|:( $%,.2f ).\n", 
                    quarterIndex + 1, companyInfo[divisionIndex][quarterIndex], difference);            
        }
    }
public static double [] calculateTotalQuarterlySales(double [][] companyInfo, int numberOfQuarters)
{
    double totalQuarterlySales; //total to accumulate sales for all quarters
    double[] totalQtSalesArray = new double[numberOfQuarters]; //array that will hold total for each quarter
    double difference = 0;
    System.out.println();

    for(int quarterIndex = 0; quarterIndex < companyInfo[0].length; quarterIndex++)
        {
        totalQuarterlySales = 0;

        for(int divisionIndex = 0; divisionIndex < companyInfo.length; divisionIndex++)
        {
            totalQuarterlySales += companyInfo[divisionIndex][quarterIndex];
        //totalQuarterlySales will increase by companyInfo
        }

        totalQtSalesArray [quarterIndex] = totalQuarterlySales;
        //check condition and calculate each division’s increase or decrease from 
        //the previous quarter starting with 
        if(quarterIndex >= 1)
        {
            difference = totalQtSalesArray[quarterIndex] - totalQtSalesArray[quarterIndex - 1];
        }

        System.out.printf("Total Sales Per Quarter |Quarter %d| $%,.2f,\t  |Difference To Previous Quarter|( $%.2f ).\n", 
                quarterIndex + 1, totalQtSalesArray[quarterIndex], difference);
    }
    //@return 
        return totalQtSalesArray;
        //reference variable that stores totalQtSalesArray array
}

//@param method To calculate the average sales for all divisions that quarter
public static void calculeQtSalesAverage(double [] totalQtSales, int numberOfDivisions) 
{
    System.out.println();
    for(int quarterlySalesIndex = 0; quarterlySalesIndex < totalQtSales.length; quarterlySalesIndex ++)
    {
        System.out.printf("Average Sales For \t|Quarter %d| $%,.2f.\n", quarterlySalesIndex + 1, 
                totalQtSales [quarterlySalesIndex] / numberOfDivisions);
    }
}

public static void showHighestSales(double [][] companyInfo)
{
    //hold highest sales value
    double highestSales;

    //hold highest sales value for a division
    int highestSalesDivisionIndex;

    for(int quarterIndex = 0; quarterIndex < companyInfo[0].length; quarterIndex++)
    {
        highestSales = 0;
        highestSalesDivisionIndex = 0;

        System.out.println();

        for(int divisionIndex = 0; divisionIndex < companyInfo.length; divisionIndex++)
        {
            //check condition for any quarterly sales for any division to be 
            if(companyInfo[divisionIndex][quarterIndex] > highestSales)
            {
                highestSales = companyInfo[divisionIndex][quarterIndex];
                highestSalesDivisionIndex = divisionIndex + 1;
            }
        }
        //display division with the highest sales for that quarter
        System.out.printf("In Quarter %d Division %d had the highest sales in the amount of:\t $%,.2f.\n",
                quarterIndex + 1, highestSalesDivisionIndex + 1, highestSales);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int numberOfDivisions = 6; //hold number of divisions
    int numberOfQuarters = 4; //hold number of quarters

    double [] totalQtSales;

    double [][] companyInfo = new double [numberOfDivisions][numberOfQuarters];

    enterSalesFigures(companyInfo);
    listSalesFigures(companyInfo);
    totalQtSales = calculateTotalQuarterlySales(companyInfo, numberOfQuarters);
    calculeQtSalesAverage(totalQtSales, numberOfDivisions);
    showHighestSales(companyInfo);
}
```

}

Comment: What about your code isn't working? What happens when you compile? Do you get errors? If so, what are they? If not, what happens when you run the program? How does the output differ from what you expect?

Comment: Where you ask for the input, you could use [`do...while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html). For example: `do {//get input} while (companyInfo [divisionIndex][divisionIndex] < 0);`

Comment: Can you also provide a [mcve] which reproduces the problem you are asking about? You should show a complete program which anyone else can compile and run if they want to.

Comment: No error message with my validation, it does not validate and let negative nr to be inputted from user. I added                                           
 do 
    {companyInfo [divisionIndex][quarterIndex] = keyboard.nextDouble();
     } while (companyInfo [divisionIndex][divisionIndex] < 0);                                                                                           but companyInfo is not being populated any more. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    double[][] companyInfo = new double[10][10];

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int divisionIndex = 0; divisionIndex < companyInfo.length; divisionIndex++)

    {
        for (int quarterIndex = 0; quarterIndex < companyInfo[0].length; quarterIndex++) {
            System.out.printf("Division %d, Quarter %d   ", divisionIndex + 1, quarterIndex + 1);
            while ((companyInfo[divisionIndex][divisionIndex] = scanner.nextDouble()) < 0) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the number that is more than or equal to one.");
                System.out.printf("Division %d, Quarter %d   ", divisionIndex + 1, quarterIndex + 1);
            }

        }
    }
```

Does it help?

Comment: Thanks, it does not print company info as 2d array any more, how can I prompt the user to enter data again? I tried to create a new method to validate and to call it from  Main, but not working either.

Comment: Are you trying to take input in single array now @Ellen ?

Comment: Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  for(int divisionIndex = 0; divisionIndex < companyInfo.length; divisionIndex++)
   {for(int quarterIndex = 0; quarterIndex < companyInfo[0].length; quarterIndex++)
   {System.out.printf("Division %d, Quarter %d   ", divisionIndex + 1, quarterIndex + 1);
companyInfo [divisionIndex][quarterIndex] = keyboard.nextDouble();
do {companyInfo [divisionIndex][quarterIndex] = keyboard.nextDouble();
} while (companyInfo [divisionIndex][divisionIndex] < 0);
{ System.out.println("Please enter the number that is more than or equal to one.");} I did this

Comment: I posted all code blocks incl Main method so you can see. Thanks much

Comment: It shows an error on quarterIndex 'cannot be resolved to a variable'.